# Evaluating an hcl.Expression which expected value is a Go interface

Tags: go, hcl

I am writing a HCL-based configuration language where some types of blocks can reference other blocks using expressions, as follows:

```
source "my_source" {
  // some blocks and attributes...

  to = destination.my_kafka_topic
}

destination "kafka" "my_kafka_topic" {
  // some blocks and attributes...
}

destination "elasticsearch" "my_es_index" {
  // some blocks and attributes...
}
```

(The goal is the model the flow of events in a messaging system, and then materialize the actual system in terms of infrastructure.)

During parsing, I simply perform a partial decoding of the static attributes and blocks and ensure "to" [`hcl.Attribute`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2@v2.9.0#Attribute)s can be interpreted as [`hcl.Traversal`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2@v2.9.0#Traversal)s, but **don't evaluate them** (yet).

```golang
type Source struct {
    Name string // first HCL tag

    /* ... */

    To hcl.Traversal
}

type Destination struct {
    Type string // first HCL tag
    Name string // second HCL tag

    /* ... */
}
```

Later, referenceable blocks (e.g. `destination` in the example above) are associated with a certain Go type based on their `Type` label, and this Go type always implements an interface called `Referenceable`.

```golang
type Referenceable interface {
    AsReference() *Destination
}

type Destination struct {
    // fields that represent the destination in terms of address, protocol, etc.
}
```

At that stage, I know how to build a map of referenceables `map[string]Referenceable` where the key is `<block_type>.<block_name>` (e.g. `"destination.my_kafka_topic"`), but I am unsure how to leverage that in an [`hcl.EvalContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2@v2.9.0#EvalContext) in order to evaluate the variables to Go `Referenceable`s.

What I would like to know is: how to express a Go interface in the [`cty` type system](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/zclconf/go-cty/cty#Value) used by `hcl.EvalContext`? Is is even possible? If not, is it advised to inject instances of `*Destination` in the `hcl.EvalContext` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I was couple of times trying to evaluate variables in HCL and always hit the wall. Their API seemed to be overly complex for such a simple thing like: defining variables at the top of the configuration file, and refer to them in the resources section.

I ended up crafting my own format, [BCL](https://github.com/wkhere/bcl), with a very similar syntax. After all, I needed syntax I liked, not the 100% compatibility with HCL (which is actually also varying - there is Terraform HCL, Packer HCL and couple of others - every app with a dependency on HCl uses it differently).

So I am not having a direct solution to your `hcl.EvalContext` problem, but I'd like to offer you at least a different context (pun intended) - a look at that [BCL](https://github.com/wkhere/bcl) project of mine. Few desirable things are missing atm, but it's handy, well tested, has a good (and correct!) generated parser and deserializes to Go structs.